# C# orderby IQueryable by 2 different properties LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable of custom objects and want to implement sorting on them. Here is a simplified form of the objects I have in the database:

```
public class OrgObject : Entity
{
    public string sortStr { get; set; }
    public int sortVal  { get; set; }
    //... more different properties
    public virtual List<LinkedObject> links {get; set;}
}

public class LinkedObject : Entity  
{
    public string sortStr { get; set; }
    public int sortVal  { get; set; }
    //... more different properties
}
```

The problem is, some of the OrgObjects have no value for sortStr(or sortVal), then it should take the sortStr of LinkedObject. 
I tried implementing a separate getter to achieve that, but LINQ does not support that.
I tried using:

```
 OrderBy(x => x.LinkedObject.sortStr).ThenBy(y => y.sortStr)
```

which doesn't work either. Is there a way to solve this with LINQ? Or any other clean and easy solution? Or do I need to implement my own?
Thanks in advance

Comment: *then it should take the sortStr of LinkedObject.* Exactly which `LinkedObject` do you have in mind - according to your model, the `OrgObject` can have **0, 1 or more** `LinkedObject`s?

Comment: It's also a custom object, pretty much like the code shows. It basically can have 0, 1 or more, but it always has at least one, when sortStr and sortVal of OrgObject are null.

Comment: In other words, you are seeking for `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the sort string and not the sort value?
It would be helpful to have an example in put and out put?

Comment: no, I'm using FirstOrDefault to get the first object of the list. I want to sort on OrgObject.sortStr and if thats null use OrgObject.LinkedObject.sortStr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you want the first or default option from the LinkedObject list then you can do something like this.

```
var ordering = o.OrderBy(x => x.sortStr ?? x.links.FirstOrDefault().sortStr);
```

Full example here:

```
var o = new List<OrgObject>()
{
    {
        new OrgObject()
        {
            sortStr = null,
            sortVal = null,
            links = new List<LinkedObject>()
            {
                new LinkedObject(){sortStr = "a", sortVal=1},
                new LinkedObject(){sortStr = "b", sortVal=2},
            }

        }
    },
    {
        new OrgObject()
        {
            sortStr = "c",
            sortVal = 3,
            links = new List<LinkedObject>()
            {
                new LinkedObject(){sortStr = "a", sortVal=1},
                new LinkedObject(){sortStr = "b", sortVal=2},
            }

        }
    },
    {
        new OrgObject()
        {
            sortStr = null,
            sortVal = null,
            links = new List<LinkedObject>()
            {
                new LinkedObject(){sortStr = "d", sortVal=1},
                new LinkedObject(){sortStr = "e", sortVal=2},
            }

        }
    },
 };

 var ordering = o.OrderBy(x => x.sortStr ?? x.links.FirstOrDefault().sortStr);
```

Comment: sry, didn't see your comment before. It has several properties on which the user can select, so it switches. But your answer looks awesome and for the first property it already works. I will try it for the others and keep you up to date. thx!

Comment: That works like a charm. It was a bit difficult to verify, but I'm quite convinced this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `IComparable<OrgObject>` in OrgObject that does your custom logic, whatever it might be, and just do `.OrderBy(x=>x)`.

Comment: Can I use it if I want to switch on what I want to sort? There are several properties on which the user can select he wants to sort it(Front end). Which would mean I have initially sorted on sortStr and can change to sorting on sortVal